# How do I enable Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, centos

Currently, I am running CentOS 7 with php 7. For the life of me, I can't get mod_rewrite working.

I am testing by using this code

```
if (function_exists("apache_get_modules")) {
$modules = apache_get_modules();
$mod_rewrite = in_array("mod_rewrite",$modules);
if($mod_rewrite)
{
    $result[] = '<span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> mod_rewrite is enabled</span>';
    $score++;
}
else
    $result[] = '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> mod_rewrite is not enabled</span>';
}
else
    $result[] = '<span class="label label-warning"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> mod_rewrite is not enabled</span>';
```

And it show "Mod_Rewrite is not enabled"

Eventhough I have added AllowOverride All to my Virtual Host in httpd.conf file

```
 <Directory "/home/mailingmm/public_html">
AllowOverride All
SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
```

Could you show me how to enable mod_rewrite? and how to test if mod_rewrite is on?

Thanks

Comment: @mario Isn't that a Debian/Ubuntu-only command? It looks to me like on CentOS you have to do things [more manually](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache-on-centos/).

Comment: What's the output of `httpd -M` ? Do you see `rewrite_module`? Which repo did you install apache from?

Comment: @Kisaragi I see this `rewrite_module (shared)`

Comment: @Mike I followed that link and follow its instruction and still can get mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` in the appropriate VirtualHost?  (or globally?)